# Replace image name on upload to the new post name on front-end form

Tags: posts, slug, title, front-end

I'm using this form to replace featured images and post title on my frontend form:

```
<form id="featured_upload" name="featured_upload" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><label for="title">Title</label><input type="text" id="title" value="<?php echo $post_to_edit->post_title; ?>" size="45" name="title" /></p>
<input type="file" name="my_image_upload" id="my_image_upload" multiple="false" required />
<p><input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="" /></p>
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_image_upload', 'my_image_upload_nonce' ); ?>
<input id="" name="" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

**Here's the saving process**

```
// Check the nonce is valid, and the user can edit this post.
if ( isset( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], $_POST['post_id'] ) 
    && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], 'my_image_upload' )
    && current_user_can( 'manage_options', $_POST['post_id'] )) {
    include('wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    include('wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    include('wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    // Let WordPress handle the upload.

    $attachmentID = get_post_thumbnail_id();                            
    $attachment_path = get_attached_file( $attachmentID);                   
    //Delete attachment from database only, not file
    $delete_attachment = wp_delete_attachment($attachmentID, true);
    //Delete attachment file from disk
    $delete_file = unlink($attachment_path);
    //Form attachment Field name.
    $file_handler = 'my_image_upload'; 
    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $_POST['post_id'] );

    //changing the post title
    if(!empty($_POST['title'])) {
    //$new_title = sanitize_title($_POST['title']);
    $new_slug = sanitize_title($_POST['title']);        
    $my_post = array('post_title' => $_POST['title'],'post_name'  => $new_slug);
    // Update new post title into the database
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

**The problem:**

I need the uploaded picture to be saved with the new post title (`$_POST['title']`)

**Example:**

The chosen image is `image1.jpg`

The new post name is `renamed post` (just like on `$_POST['title']`)

On the upload process, `image1.jpg` should be renamed to `renamed-post.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sanitize_file_name` filter to rename file. put this code in active theme's functions.php, this will rename image filename as postname if only get `title` request. I have tested this code and it is working fine. 
Post name : https://prnt.sc/q3thzw
Uploaded renamed image : https://prnt.sc/q3tib7

```
function make_filename_as_post_name($filename) {
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename($filename, $ext);
    $new_name = $_REQUEST['title'];
    if(!empty($new_name)){
        # Replace space with dash 
        $new_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $new_name);
        return $new_name . $ext;
    }else{
        return $name . $ext;
    }
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'make_filename_as_post_name', 10);
```

let me know if this works for you!

Comment: The `$_REQUEST['title']` refers to the title field on my form, right? This would not change image name when they are uploaded on `wp-admin` back-end, right?

Comment: Yes. i have tested.

Comment: You have tested to replace only image names submitted on the form with input field with ID title? Sorry, but I have to be sure on this...

Comment: yes i have submitted form and image name renamed as post name. i have also upload image using media uploader,  i have not found any issue in that. let ne know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks!! It works!